# How do you update a column with the enumerate function?

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to update a column with a grade (a*,a,b,c...) depending on where a student's mark land within the grade boundaries. 
The user has already specified what marks you need to get the required grade.

I've tried using the enumerate function, going through each record along with a list of the student's mark (called listy)

```
while True:
  try:
     a_star = int(input("Raw mark to get A*: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

while True:
  try:
    a = int(input("Raw mark to get A: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

while True:
  try:
    b = int(input("Raw mark to get B: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

while True:
  try:
    c = int(input("Raw mark to get C: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

while True:
  try:
    d = int(input("Raw mark to get D: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

while True:
  try:
    e = int(input("Raw mark to get E: "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Has to be a valid number")
    continue
  else :
    break

listy = []

for i in raw_mark:
  raw_mark_ = i[3]
  listy.append(raw_mark_)

# print("This is listy: ", listy)

for i, val in enumerate(listy):
  if val >= a_star:
    grade = "A*"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

  elif val >= a and i < a_star:
    grade = "A"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

  elif val >= b and i < a:
    grade = "B"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

  elif val >= c and i < b:
    grade = "C"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

  elif val >= d and i < c:
    grade = "D"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

  else :
    grade = "E"
    c.execute("UPDATE class SET grade = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", (grade, (i + 1), ))
    # conn.commit()

conn.commit()
```

this is the error i get:

> elif val >=c and i=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'sqlite3.Cursor'

Comment: We need to see all variable assignments. Please show origination of *a_star* and lettered objects.

Comment: Edited. They are integer values so I don't understand what the error is? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are overwriting the *c* variable. Initially, it is defined as integer object:

```
c = int(input("Raw mark to get C: "))
```

But then is later defined as cursor object:

```
c = conn.cursor()
```

Simply, change the cursor object name and all its references thereafter:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
```

---

Also, likely you meant to use `val` for lower and upper limit of range logic, not the enumerate variable, `i`:

```
elif val >= a and val < a_star:
...
elif val >= b and val < a:
...
elif val >= c and val < b:
...
elif val >= d and val < c:
...
```

---

With all that said, consider using SQL's `CASE` statement for a more compact check across interval ranges using named parameters:

```
for i, val in enumerate(listy):
  sql = '''UPDATE class
           SET grade = CASE 
                         WHEN :val_prm >= :a_star_prm THEN 'A*'
                         WHEN :val_prm >= :a_prm AND :val_prm < :a_star_prm THEN 'A'
                         WHEN :val_prm >= :b_prm AND :val_prm < :a_prm THEN 'B'
                         WHEN :val_prm >= :c_prm AND :val_prm < :b_prm THEN 'C'
                         WHEN :val_prm >= :d_prm AND :val_prm < :c_prm THEN 'D'
                         ELSE 'E'
                       END
           WHERE id = :id_prm + 1;
        '''
  cur.execute(sql, {'val_prm': val, 'a_star_prm': a_star, 'a_prm': a, 
                    'b_prm': b, 'c_prm': c, 'd_prm': d, 'id_prm': i})
  conn.commit()
```

---

Even better, store the `val` or `raw_mark` in table alongside `grade` column to eliminate the need of loop and `WHERE` clause. Table aliases are added for illustration:

```
sql = '''UPDATE class c
         SET c.grade = CASE 
                         WHEN c.raw_mark >= :a_star_prm THEN 'A*'
                         WHEN c.raw_mark >= :a_prm AND c.raw_mark < :a_star_prm THEN 'A'
                         WHEN c.raw_mark >= :b_prm AND c.raw_mark < :a_prm THEN 'B'
                         WHEN c.raw_mark >= :c_prm AND c.raw_mark < :b_prm THEN 'C'
                         WHEN c.raw_mark >= :d_prm AND c.raw_mark < :c_prm THEN 'D'
                         ELSE 'E'
                       END;
      '''
cur.execute(sql, {'a_star_prm':a_star, 'a_prm':a, 'b_prm':b, 'c_prm':c, 'd_prm':d})
conn.commit()
```